Bash pipe vs redirect?
I am working with the Orca quantum chemistry software on Linux. It doesn't accept input through stdin, but does accept input through a file. I want to generate these input files on-the-fly using a bash script and pipe them in, so I wrote a script called orca_stdin.sh: (note that fd0 is a symbolic link to /dev/fd0 since Orca tries to write output files in the same directory as the input files)
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cd $(dirname $0)
cd workdir

orca fd0

rm fd0_* fd0.*

And I tested it with:
./orca_stdin.sh < test.inp

... where test.inp is a valid input file.
However, oddly, when I run:
cat test.inp | ./orca_stdin.sh

The program hangs. This is a problem since I want to have another script generate the input file, so I can only use a pipe.
This would be the wrong place to ask about Orca, of course, and there are plenty of workarounds to this issue, one of which I have adopted without problem. However, this issue raises a question: How are a redirect in and a cat to a pipe functionally any different for the recipient of the pipe?

The redirection provides a real, seekable handle. The pipe provides a FIFO that can only be read once, front-to-back with no ability to rewind, fast forward, check its size in constant time, or do any of the other nifty things one can do with a real file handle.

@CharlesDuffy with that said, if you created a named pipe would that solve the OP's issue without needing a more permanent file?  Something like mkfifo mypipe && write_to_pipe.sh && ./orca_stdin.sh < mypipe ? Although I'm not sure what the benefit of this approach would be compared to simply writing to a file.

@h0r53, the semantics are identical between named and anonymous pipes after they're open, so no, that won't help.

@somebody0 - Building off my last comment, since pipes and files are treated differently, I think you could still workaround your issue by writing the configuration to a temporary file and reading it within a one-liner. write_configuration.sh > test.inp && ./orca_stdin.sh < test.inp

We'd want to trace the program being run (as with strace, sysdig, or similar) to figure out what it's trying to do when it hangs -- can't really speak to a fix until we've run down an immediate cause.

Thanks for the suggestions! I'm currently writing to a temp file as suggested above; just wanted to clarify why this is necessary

Piping is a form of redirection.

cat file | cmd is known as a "useless use of cat" (UUoC).  There are multiple problems with it.  Some of them are explained in BashFAQ/119 - What's the difference between "cmd < file" and "cat file | cmd"? What is a UUOC?.

Assuming that cat test.inp is a placeholder for running some other command, try cat test.inp | ./orca_stdin.sh - with a - as the input file name. Many programs will read from stdin given an argument of -, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41829/133219.

@EdMorton, ...true, but if ./orca_stdin.sh <test.inp worked, we know that an explicit - isn't needed in this particular case.

(There are also syscalls like pread() that take an offset to work from as part of their arguments; obviously, any program that relies on those calls won't work with any kind of non-seekable input source).


How are a redirect in and a cat to a pipe functionally any different for the recipient of the pipe?

The < operator causes the specified file to be opened for reading and connected to the process's file descriptor 0.  This is similar to (and perhaps implemented as) ...
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd, 0);
        // ...
    }

... with appropriate error checking.
This leaves stdin connected to the file descriptor of a regular file.  In particular, that file descriptor is seekable.
The | operator causes a pipe to be created, the write end to be connected to the stdout of the left-hand process, and the read end to be connected to the read end of the right-hand process.  This is similar to (and perhaps implemented as) ...
    int pipe_fds[2];
    pipe(pipe_fds);

    pid_t left_process = fork();
    if (left_process == 0) {
        // child process
        dup2(pipe_fds[1], 1);
        close(pipe_fds[0]);
        // ...
    }

    pid_t right_process = fork();
    if (right_process == 0) {
        // child process
        dup2(pipe_fds[0], 0);
        close(pipe_fds[1]);
        // ...
    }

    // parent process (shell)
    close(pipe_fds[0]);
    close(pipe_fds[1]);

... with appropriate error checking.
This leaves stdin of the right-hand process connected to the file descriptor of a pipe.  In particular, that file descriptor probably is not seekable.
Among programs that require an input file to be designated by name, there are some for which that is a relatively arbitrary choice.  But there are others that genuinely require the properties of a regular file (most often seekability).  It sounds like your orca is among the latter.

Side note:

I want to have another script generate the input file, so I can only use a pipe.

There may indeed be reasons why it is convenient or even (less likely) necessary to convey input from the generator script via a pipe, but the mere fact that there is a generator script is not one of them.  As an alternative, you could have the generator script write its output to a temp file.  Or maybe even a not-so-temp file, which might be important for tracing results back to input details, or re-running, or performing variant runs.

You may use named pipes in linux, it is a file special, which can be written by one process and read by other process, like that:
mkfifo mypipe

cat mypipe &

echo "something" > mypipe

so, cat is just reading the file, but the file is not a regular file, it is just a "fifo" file special, and cat command will wait for any other process write something to this mypipe "file"

How does this fix the OP's problem? A program that needs a "real" file (one that allows seek(), tell(), &c) will generally fail with a named FIFO just as much as an anonymous one.

How about:
cat $@ >temp_file
orca temp_file
rm temp_file

you mat need to use name for the temp_file that you won't use anywhere else.

$@ unquoted has all the bugs of $*; it should be cat -- "$@" to work with all possible filenames. More pertinently, the OP already knows how to work around the problem; they asked for an explanation, not an additional workaround.
